# How to find the Tangential Speed?

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

This is the problem:

An airplane accelerates at $47.5/s^2$ while turning through a loop $500$ m. Calculate the plane's tangential speed.

I have tried up and down to solve this problem. The only formulas in my module's lesson are $ac = v^2/r$ and $v = 2(\pi)r/T$ . I can't get a solution to the problem from any of the formulas. I have tried googling but I am unable to find any solution.

This is Gr.8 Physics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The acceleration (resulting from the centripetal force) is $a=v^2/r$. Plug in $r=500\text{ m}$ and $a=47.5\text{ ms}^{-2}$ and you will get $v=\sqrt{ar}\approx 154\text{ ms}^{-1}$.